# User.IsInRole returning false with local groups

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, windows-authentication

I have a ASP MVC application where I want to use Windows Authentication. On my development machine I created a local group where I added my account. When I run the application with Visual Studio I can see that in the User object in my controller method contains my account. However User.IsInRole(local group name) returns false. 
My web.config looks like this

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
```

How can I get this to work on my machine?

I don't want to use an Authorize attribute on the methods because I want the group name to be configurable, so I have to do through code. And I can not get it to work either.

Comment: Not using Authorize is a really really bad idea.  Instead why don't you derive from Authorize and build the custom logic in the attribute?

Comment: Are you on an Active Directory domain?  And what did your `User.IsInRole()` code look like?

Comment: Do you have a reason for using impersonation?  There are very rare circumstances that using impersonation is a good idea, you may not even need it.

Comment: Impersonation is not necessary, I added it because maybe it would solve my problem, but apparently it doesn't. Adding the authorize attribute on the method doesn't make a difference either. I don't want to add the authorize attribute with the roles specified, because  I want to keep the group configurable through the web.config.

Comment: I didn't say add the authorize attribute on the method, I said derive your own from authorizeattribute, then you are; A using the built in security model, which has been tested works, and B it can do whatever you want it to, because you write the code, and C it becomes reusable, so you have consistent (DRY) code.

Comment: Thanks Erik, with the custom authorizeattribute you put me on the right track to get nice and clean code for authorization

Answer (score 4):

Found my problem. I have to log out and log in again to make the changes to groups for an account visible in the application.

Comment: I had the same problem, but in addition had to make sure I was physically connected to the company network during login. With a WiFi connection that didn't come alive until after logging in, I was going round in circles wondering why my account wasn't picking up the new group memberships!